# docker base image repository ouside Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, dockerhub

I'm new to Docker. Is it possible to have a Docker base image repository outside Docker Hub? Let's say store them in your cloud rather than having DH account? Thanks.

Comment: Try searching SO for “Docker private registry”; there are a half-dozen good questions that cover different aspects of this.  You need to include the registry hostname in image names (`registry.example.com/image:tag`) but this works in all contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You can host your own registry as you would like.  Full details of hosting one's own registry server can be found at [Deploy a registry server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/).

The the highest level, the following will suffice:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Some cloud providers give you your own registries ready to use.  For example, Google [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/).

Comment: Does this apply for base images? Once in the registry, can those new image be used as base images as well?

Comment: My understanding is that a custom registry can be the source of any images you may need.  Think of Docker Hub as simply being a managed/curated registry and that a custom registry can be used just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Google has its own registry for containers which I assume may be relevant based on the GCP tag. Check out the Google Container Registry at gcr.io. You can upload and pull containers from there just as you would with the Docker Hub.